# jackson jboss eap6.1.1 annotations not working

Tags: java, annotations, jackson, json-deserialization, jboss-eap-6

I have been trying to get Jackson annotations working in the JBoss RestEasy application on a EAP 6.1.1 server. To be more exact I want to get the [JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization) working through there annotation like done [here](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html).

Now it seems simple enough but for some reason it’s not really working.
I got the following code:

```
package example.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type",visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImplementedRequest.class, name = "implementedrequest")})
public abstract class Request {

}
```

And the implementation of the abstract class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type", visible = true)
public class ImplementedRequestextends Request {
    @NotEmpty
    private Person applicant;

    private List<AbstractApplicationPart> applications;

}
```

I created a endpoint that makes a request and processes a request:

```
@Path("serviceRequest")
@Named("RequestResource")
@RequestScoped
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ValidateRequest
@IgnoreMediaTypes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class RequestResource {
   public Boolean saveRequest( @Valid Request request, @Context HttpServletRequest req) throws JAXBException, AnError {
//Some awesome processing happens here
}
public Response getDummyData() {
// Creates and fills the ImplementedRequestextends
return result;
}
}
```

Now I also did some configuration and made sure I load the Jackson modules in Jboss with the war deployment. And made sure in my pom I have the same version as the Modules.

My expectation is now that if I do a call I get something like:

```
{
    "applicant": { "name":"Dummy data", "age":31},
    "applications": [ {"sport":"soccer"},{"sport":"judo"}    ]
}
```

I was expecting to get a `@type` name with the field `implementedrequest`. This is my first attempt; eventually I also want to have the abstract array work like this. But I can't even get this working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to upgrade to Jackson 2.1.4, Jersey ignoring the annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15436268/unable-to-upgrade-to-jackson-2-1-4-jersey-ignoring-the-annotations)

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I figured out what went wrong.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
```

Is the problem. Jackson has 2 versions and both work, but the default for JBoss EAP6.1.1 is the 1.X branch wich is available under `org.codehaus`. The problem both methods work under the core. It's later moved to a different branch and artifact.